# Sequelize findOne(...).get is not a function

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a database using sequelize and sqlite but for some reason .get is not a function even though it shows up in autoCompletion
This is my code:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  raw: false,
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "databasetest.sqlite",
  logging: false
});
const test = sequelize.define("test", {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  }
}, {

});
test.sync({ force: true });
test.create({
  name: "Hid",
  id: "123"
});

console.log(test.findOne({ where: { id: "123" } }).get("name"));
```

And this is the error:

```
console.log(test.findOne({ where: { id: "123" } }).get("name"));
                                                   ^

TypeError: test.findOne(...).get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Rilea/test.js:27:52)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.sync()` is asynchronous. You have to `await` it before you can successfully start querying. Same goes for `.create()`. All of that stuff is covered in the examples in the "Getting Started" section of the Sequelize website.

Comment: I added it and now it says this:
await test.sync({ force: true });
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Yes, correct. Again, that's all in the sample bits of code in the "Getting Started" section.